# Send Parse Push to everyone from Android App

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

Maybe anyone can help me ! I want to send a push notification just to every registered device from a simple android app. (to everyone). There are working examples how to make this possible with php but i don´t know how to send a push notification to all (without channel) to all ?

I have found this information so far but its not working

My Channel is "" and the goal is to send a push to all devices !

```
    ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", "");


  ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
        push.setMessage("Hello world!");
        push.sendInBackground();
```

I have changed my code like this but it is still not working !

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("bugatti", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });


  ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
       pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", "bugatti");

   ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
      push.setQuery(pushQuery); 
        push.setChannel("bugatti");
        push.setMessage("Hello world!");
        push.sendInBackground();
```

Would be nice if anybody could help me !

Comment: why not just create a channel that all devices subscribe to?

Comment: i have tested it with subscribing to a channel "bugatti" but it is still not working :(

Comment: Client push enabled was off ....:) solved

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable "Sending Notifications".

1. Go to Parse.com
2. Go to settings
3. Go to Push
4. Go to "Client push enabled?"
5. Set it on.

Enjoy!